# Will a contempt of congress lawsuit actually reach the merits?

Tags: constitutional-law, first-amendment, congress

Hypothetical Scenario: Kellyanne Conway is subpoenaed by the House Oversight committee for Hatch Act violations. Conway appears but tells the chairman that he is a fraudulent partisan grandstander, a disgrace to Congress and is carrying out a ridiculous preposterous hearing that she feels is absolutely unpredicated on any legal basis and that she will not give credibility to the hearing by answering even a single question. But keep in mind, she honored the subpoena and showed up for the hearing.

Now, the House holds her in contempt for insulting the chairman and refusing to answer questions and applies the imprisonment penalty to her. She appeals her penalty to the courts saying that her first amendment rights are being violated as the government is penalizing her for speaking her mind and compelling her to speak against her intent.

Will this case be decided on the merit of Conway's contention - that the investigation is fraudulent (that is her reasons for not answering questions and berating the chairman) or will it only be decided on the statue that Congress has the power to hold her in contempt and the courts will not second-guess Congress' decision and accept whatever reason Congress gives them?

Comment: This question seems to misunderstand "the merits."  The merits of a protester's first amendment case do not concern whether the protester is right.  Here the merits of the case would be precisely what the question seems to assume they are not: whether "Congress has the power to hold her in contempt."  That doesn't imply that the courts must accept congress's reasoning without question, however.

Comment: Merely showing up to testify does not "honor" the subpoena.  You have to actually answer the questions put to you, truthfully, unless you have some specific Constitutional right to refuse (e.g. the answer would incriminate you, executive privilege, etc).  It doesn't matter whether answering is "against your intent", whatever that means.

Comment: @phoog Thanks. Per your response what would the courts look into - the reason for holding her in contempt? Or could they go even one level deeper and look into their reasons for investigating her in the first place?

Comment: There are some notes about the subpoena power on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contempt_of_Congress#Subpoenas), with references to relevant cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A similar question was considered by the Supreme Court in [*Eastland v. United States Servicemen's Fund*, 421 U.S. 491 (1975)](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/421/491/).  The Court held, citing precedent, that if the Committee's activities are within the "legitimate legislative sphere" then the courts cannot interfere with the subpoena, since the Speech and Debate clause of the Constitution forbids those members of Congress from being "questioned in any other place" about their Congressional activities.  The standard set in *Gravel v. United States* is whether the subpoena is

> "an integral part of the deliberative and communicative processes by which Members participate in committee and House proceedings with respect to the consideration and passage or rejection of proposed legislation or with respect to other matters which the Constitution places within the jurisdiction of either House."

Or, as written more succinctly in *McGrain v. Daugherty*,

> The subject of any inquiry always must be one "on which legislation could be had."

So your hypothetical Conway could sue to claim that the subpoena is improper; but she would have to show that it does not pass the test given above.  This seems difficult, in general.  As long as the inquiry *could* be related to passing legislation or other legitimate purposes, the courts won't question whether that actually *is* the Committee's motivation.

Comment: I would have thought so too that the courts wouldn't presume to think motivation would be reviewable as long as there "could be... other legitimate purposes". But didn't Chief Justice Roberts essentially rule in the recent Department of Commerce v. New York case that motivation was, in fact, reviewable and he denied the Executive Branch the opportunity to proceed with their census question because he found the motivation suspect? If courts can review the motivations of decisions made by the Executive Branch, can't they also then review the motivations of Congressional committees?

Comment: In the case of executive branch action, Congress has enacted the [Administrative Procedures Act](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/5/706), which specifically empowers the courts to examine such actions and set them aside if they are "arbitrary, capricious, an abuse of discretion, or otherwise not in accordance with the law".  There is no such statute or Constitutional provision applying to the actions of Congress.  The courts have no power to set aside a Congressional subpoena even if it is arbitrary and capricious, as long as it still relates to legislation.

Comment: @NonPartisanObservor legislative motivation *is* reviewable.  For a court to decide whether the motivation is related to "the legitimate legislative sphere," it must review the motivation.  But in other contexts, review of motivation may go deeper, especially if there is a statute that requires an executive act to have a motivation that meets more exacting standards.

Comment: @NateEldredge Does that mean these committees are effectively above the law?

Answer (score 13):

"Contempt of Congress" does not extend, in a legal sense, to insulting Congress as a whole, one house, a committee chair, or a member. (Congress and its committees have power to require both members and witnesses to abide by its rules of decorum, which forbid such insults, but as far as I know the remedy is merely to remove the disorderly person.)

Contempt of congress is defined by [2 USC 192](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/2/192), which provides that:

> Every person who having been summoned as a witness by the authority of either House of Congress to give testimony or to produce papers upon any matter under inquiry before either House, or any joint committee established by a joint or concurrent resolution of the two Houses of Congress, or any committee of either House of Congress, willfully makes default, or who, having appeared, refuses to answer any question pertinent to the question under inquiry, shall be deemed guilty of a misdemeanor, punishable by a fine of not more than $1,000 nor less than $100 and imprisonment in a common jail for not less than one month nor more than twelve months.

Note that this is a Federal criminal statute like any other, and Congress does not normally "declare" a person guilty, much less "apply the imprisonment penalty". Charges would have to be brought before a federal court, and the person convicted by a jury, or by a judge if a jury trial was waived.

Congress does have the "inherent power" to hold trials for contempt itself, but this has not been done since 1934. This power was upheld by the Supreme Cout in [*Anderson v. Dunn* 19 U.S. 204 (1821)](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/19/204/)

A conviction under 2 USC 192 for refusal to answer questions on the part of a witness under subpoena was upheld against a First Amendment challenge in *Wilkinson v. United States*, 365 U.S. 399 (1961) In that case, according to the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contempt_of_Congress#Subpoenas), a standard for testing subpoenas was declared by the US Supreme court:

> As announced in *Wilkinson v. United States*, a Congressional committee must meet three requirements for its subpoenas to be "legally sufficient." First, the committee's investigation of the broad subject area must be authorized by its chamber; second, the investigation must pursue "a valid legislative purpose" but does not need to involve legislation and does not need to specify the ultimate intent of Congress; and third, the specific inquiries must be pertinent to the subject matter area that has been authorized for investigation.

Thus, in considering such charges, it is a proper defense that the subject matter of the hearing was not withing the power of Congress to investigate, or that the questions were not relevant to the subject. The court would consider these issues if they were raised by the defense. But the political "merits" of the investigation -- whether it is a wise use of the Congressional power, would not be considered.

Comment: Thank you for your response. If I am understanding this considering, the violation, and liability if any, would arise from refusing to answer the questions. Insulting members of the committee by itself would not sustain a contempt of congress indictment?

Comment: @Non Not under 2 USC 192, at least. Congress and its committees have power to require both members and  witnesses to abide by its rules of decorum, which forbid such insults, but as far as I know the remedy is merely to remove the disorderly person.

Comment: Thanks again. I wonder then if there is no jeopardy of penalty, why don't witnesses before congressional committees openly berate them. That would at least suggest to me that even in the absence of actual legal jeopardy, witnesses do fear retribution from Congress which chills their ability to ridicule committee members openly even if they want to.

Comment: @NonPartisanObservor: If they start insulting the committee or otherwise acting disorderly, they can be removed; but this does not relieve them of their obligation to testify.  They can continue to be recalled until they decide to behave, which will be very disruptive to their life.  Then again, there's the fact that they will look like a jerk on TV.

Comment: @NonPartisanObservor: There's also a provision of the District of Columbia Code that forbids "loud, threatening or abusive language" in the Capitol, or disrupting any session of Congress.  [DC Code § 10–503.16](https://code.dccouncil.us/dc/council/code/sections/10-503.16.html).  They can be arrested by the Capitol Police and prosecuted in the DC Superior Court ([DC Code § 10–503.18](https://code.dccouncil.us/dc/council/code/sections/10-503.18.html).  The punishment is a fine of up to $500 and imprisonment for up to six months.

Comment: It seems to be mainly intended to apply to disorderly spectators, but I don't see any reason why it couldn't also apply to witnesses.  You might be able to raise a First Amendment defense, but I think this might fall under the [time, place and manner exceptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_of_speech_in_the_United_States#Time,_place,_and_manner_restrictions).

Comment: @NateEldredge: The applicability of time, place, and manner restrictions to such a case is... unclear, at best. The witness didn't choose to be there, so it's certainly not going to fall under a "time" or "place" restriction. If they got out of their seat and made a scene, manner restrictions might be plausible, but if they just said a bunch of nasty things in a calm tone of voice, I'm skeptical it would be upheld.

Comment: In Congressional testimony, you still have a right against self-incrimination, so invoking 5th amendment rights against questions that would require you to either testify to law-breaking acts or perjure yourself are valid defenses against such lines of questioning.  As Conway is being subpoenaed for a violation of a law she can invoke a her 5th amendment rights not to answer a question because it could provide incriminating answer.  Such an invocation can not be held as evidence of guilt to any crime.  Contempt only attaches then if she failed to show up.

Comment: @Kevin Ordinary courts can and routinely do enforce decorum against witnesses under subpoena, enforced by imprisonment for contempt. These do not fall to a first amendment defense. I don't see why the case should be different here.

Comment: @hszmv That would depend on the exact questions asked. The question must be one the answer to which could be taken as evidence of guilt, or used to find such evidence, for the 5th to apply. And Congress can grant, and has granted in the past, "use" immunity in order to compel testimony after a witness invokes the 5th. It is true that refusing to answer by invoking the 5th  is not contempt. But it must be separately invoked for each question, and non-incriminating questions must still be answered.

Comment: @DavidSiegel: Because Congress is an inherently political body, as opposed to the fact-finding focus of the judiciary. Political speech is subject to a heightened level of protection, as it is intimately connected with the democratic process, and is arguably the whole point of even having a First Amendment.

Comment: @Kevin You exactly hit on the scenario I had in mind. That if a witness told in a calm voice that the members of the committee were fraudulent con-artists out to get her and that the entire hearing was a public spectacle and that she had little to no respect for the members of the committee, she would still escape contempt charges. It can't be a crime to speak your mind to politicians even if they don't like it. That's democracy, right?

Comment: @kevin An interesting point, but I don't think it conveys the kind of absolute immunity you are suggesting. Bearing in mind that the witness can always go to the Capitol front steps right after the hearing adjourns for the day, and tell any reporters what jerks the committee are, requiring a witness to follow the standard congressional rules of decorum during the hearing is not exactly the same as a gag order.

Comment: @Non that depends when and where and how you do the speaking. Disrupting a hearing, even one you were compelled to be at, by "speaking your mind" in a way that violates the generally applicable rules of Congressional decorum (which allow you to condemn "measures but not men" ) would not, i think, be protected speech, although saying the exact same things outside the hearing would be. However, I don't know of a court case on point for this.

Comment: @David: I never said "absolute immunity." I said I thought prosecution was a long shot.

Comment: @DavidSiegel A court can compel testimony through subpoena and also order the person to maintain decorum, I think the same line of logic applies to Congress.  They have the subpoena power because the Legislature has a compelling interest in hearing testimony for legislative purposes, so they also have the power to force the person giving the testimony to follow the rules of decorum.  The rules exist to further Congress' legislative purpose, by keeping things on track, keeping sessions palatable for the general public so they can be appraised of what their government is doing, etc.

Comment: Re: "non-incriminating questions must still be answered." It has become very obvious that in today's political climate the reason for questioning many, if not most, political opponents is to somehow catch them in a perjury trap. We've seen people charged and bankrupted and eventually forced to plea even though they never lied. Does it not make sense that providing ANY answers at all might incriminate oneself. Thus, it seems the 5th should be allowable for every single question.

Comment: @Dunk That may make sense, at least arguably, but it is not the law. The law is that one may invoke  a 5th amendment privilege only if a question could reasonably be used to incriminate the witness in a later proceeding.  The classic response is "I have consulted my attorney, and been advised that this question might tend to incriminate me, so i respectfully decline to answer". If the comitte thinks this invalid, a court case could result. Note that immunity can be granted to compel testimony. Immunity prevents invoking the 5th, and means that the govt may not use answers against wit.

Comment: @DavidSiegel - If testimony is compelled then either a blanket "I don't remember" to every question or preface every answer with "I don't recall exactly so my answer might not be accurate but I seem to recall....".  IOW, I don't see how someone can be forced to testify and then expect to get any meaningful answers from the person unless that person was already willing to testify but needed to put on a show to make it seem like they did not want to testify.

Comment: @DavidSiegel "_generally applicable rules of Congressional decorum_" are still a restriction on political speech, so you seem to be saying that the Congress is above the Bill of Right